# Em uma frase, como saber qual a palavra com menos caracteres?

Tags: javascript, array

Em uma frase, como saber qual a palavra com menos caracteres?

O que fiz foi transformar a string num array, mas só consegui retornar o menor
quando se trata de um array de números, usando `Array.min`.

Tem alguma forma melhor de conseguir retornar a menor string de texto?

```
var strt = 'hello world'
var result = strt.split('')
console.log(typeof(result))

Array.min = function(result) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, result);
    console.log(Array.min(result))
};
console.log(Array.min(result))
```

Comment: Veja [estas respostas](https://coderbyte.com/information/Longest%20Word) para a palavra mais longa e é possível realizar a lógica inversa.

Answer (score 3):

Sabendo que cada palavra é separada por espaço, basta dividir sua frase em palavras com  `frase.split(' ');`, depois basta verificar qual a palavra com o menor tamanho através da propriedade `length`.

```js
function MenorPalavra(frase) {
    var palavras = frase.split(' ');
    let menor = palavras[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
        menor = palavras[i].length < menor.length ? palavras[i] : menor;
    }
    return menor;
}
console.log(MenorPalavra("a menor palavra deste texto é a letra a"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Achei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124172/javascript-reduce-to-find-the-shortest-word-in-a-string) no SOEN:

```
function findShortestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  var shortest = words.reduce((shortestWord, currentWord) => {
    return currentWord.length < shortestWord.length ? currentWord : shortestWord;
  }, words[0]);
  return shortest;
}
console.log(findShortestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

De quebra a função para achar a maior palavra numa frase:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longest = str.split(' ').reduce((longestWord, currentWord) =>{
    return currentWord.length > longestWord.length ? currentWord : longestWord;
  }, "");
  return longest;
}
console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Todas as respostas retornam a primeira menor palavra da string baseada no comprimento da palavra.

Mas se precisar que o JavaScript decida informar a menor entre as menores palavras de mesmo comprimento, como por exemplo, entre `a` e `b` ou entre `B` e `a` ou entre `uma` e `com`?

Veja os resultados a seguir:

```js
("b"<"a") ? console.log("b é menor que a"): console.log("b não é menor que a");

("B"<"a") ? console.log("B é menor que a"): console.log("B não é menor que a");

("áma"<"com") ? console.log("áma é menor que com"): console.log("áma não é menor que com");
```

**Regra geral para comparações de string com JavaScript.**

Para comparações de strings, o JavaScript converte cada caractere de uma string com seu valor ASCII. Cada caractere, começando com o operador da esquerda, é comparado com o caractere correspondente no operador da direita.

Entenda que o JavaScript não compara `7` com `8` e sim os seus valores ASCII
que são respectivamente `055` e `056`

> No caso de `a` com `b` compara `097` (a) com `098`(b)
>
> No caso de `B` com `a` compara `066` (B) com `097`(a)
>
> No caso de `áma` com `com` compara `225 109 097`*(áma)* com `099 111 109`*(com)*.  Dessa forma, da esquerda para a direita `099` é menor que `225`

### Para esse tipo de comparação o código é:

```js
function MenorMesmo(str) {
      var strSplit = str.split(' '),
      maisLonga, menor, menorOld;
      maisLonga = strSplit.length;
      
      for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
      
        if(strSplit[i].length <= maisLonga){
         maisLonga = strSplit[i].length;
            menor = strSplit[i] ;
            menor>menorOld?menor=menorOld:menor;
            menorOld=strSplit[i];
         }

      }
return menor;
}

console.log(MenorMesmo("Se perguntar ao JavaScript qual é a menor palavra entre todas as de menores comprimento E u U a A Á ÁUÁ quem você acha que retornará"));

console.log(MenorMesmo('uma frase com duas palavras com mesmo comprimento quero saber qual palavra será considerada menor pelo JavaScript, isso mesmo porque HUMANOS responderão primeira que lerem'));
```

[**ASCII Table**](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)

> OBS: para valores numéricos, os resultados são iguais aos que você esperaria das suas aulas de álgebra da escola

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples usando o [método `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var strt  = 'Em uma frase como saber qual palavra com menos caractetes';
var strt2 = 'tem algum metodo ou melhor forma de conseguir retornar a menor string de texto';

console.log(curta(strt));  // exemplo 1
console.log(curta(strt2)); // exemplo 2

function curta(i){
   var idx, pal;
   i.split(' ').filter(a=>{
      if(!idx || a.length < idx) idx = a.length, pal = a;
   });
   return pal;
}
```

O `filter` irá percorrer a string convertida em array com `split` e o `if` irá verificar qual é a mais curta. O parâmetro `a` do `filter` representa a string de cada índice da array.

Comment: Faltou o length. rs

Comment: Tio, não era isso que me referia, veja minha resposta que tu vai entender o que eu queria dizer.

Comment: Entendi agora. Mas na minha opinião, comparar meta-valores da string não vem muito ao caso, eu acho.